# Maven, Ant (or Apache Thrift) times out during make. Where to place proxy settings?

Tags: maven, ant, build, proxy, thrift

I am installing a software (Apache Thrift) by simply using the provided make file. When I run make per guide, I get:

```
Buildfile: /home/john/thrift/lib/java/build.xml

setup.init:

mvn.ant.tasks.check:

proxy:

mvn.ant.tasks.download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
      [get] To: /home/john/thrift/lib/java/build/tools/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar

mvn.init:
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Overriding profile: 'maven-ant-tasks-repo-profile' (source: pom) with new instance from source: pom
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:dependencies] Error transferring file: Connection timed out
```

It sure looks like proxy issues so I configure my proxy settings in maven conf file `/usr/share/maven2/conf/settings.xml`. When that did not work still, from the terminal, I do

`export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=[MyProxyName] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[MyProxyPort] -Dhttps.proxyHost=[MyProxyName] -Dhttps.proxyPort=[MyProxyPort]"`

and run `make` again. This time I got past the line `mvn.ant.tasks.download` above, but `mvn.init` times out.

What is the proper place to set proxy settings so Maven and Ant can pick up those settings? Or perhaps specify those settings in Thrift configuration file, .pom file or something like that?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. You can put proxy settings in ~/.m2/settings.xml.

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>http_proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>YOUR_HOST</host>
      <port>YOUR_PORT</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```